# xslt node set example

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, node-set

How can I use java and xslt 1.0 to pass a node set as a parameter?

I am interested to see how a node set is formed on the java side.`

```
node-set()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need the `xxx:node-set()` extension function in order to pass a node-set as an external/global parameter to a transformation and then access it inside the transformation**.

Just read the documentation of your specific XSLT processor for examples.

One suitable place to look at are the examples of the Saxon XSLT processor, that come together with its API/Code .

For example, this one:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/samples/jdom.xml